# How can I get what went wrong in initialization of OpenCV's VideoCapture?

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling

I want to open video file `dt_passat.mpg` with OpenCV. I use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture capture("dt_passat.mpg");
    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "ERR: capture is not opened" << std::endl;
        getchar();
        return -1;
    }
}
```

However, it fails, and I don't know why. How can I get the point of the problem with initialization of VideoCapture (not found file/corrupted file/unknown codec/etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opencv image/video/camera IO and gui are really only meant to get sample data in and out to test algorithms to make a real application you need a more capable general library for system stuff.

However the actual image processing algorithms are pretty good quality.

Comment: Interesting point. which library or tools would you suggest for video I/O functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, OpenCV does not always have the best documentation.

You can try looking at the internal error code using `cvGetErrorStatus()` and then turn that into a readable string with `cvErrorStr()`. See http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#cvGetErrStatus

Comment: Have you installed the optional dependencies such as ffmpeg, libgstreamer, libv4l, libxine, unicap, libdc1394 2.x if you use linux as described in http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to do it. It helped, thanks. But still, doesn't OpenCV have mechanism for reporting error reasons?

Comment: OpenCV has the `cvGetErrorStatus()` but the high-level, HighGUI-part is lacking in many areas. See answer from @martin